# High Availability of GKE regional Cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We have regional cluster in GKE, where our workloads are deployed in one of the zone. In case of failure in that specific zone will GKE automatically migrate our workloads in another zone? I have read gke docs and my understanding is that it should migrate workloads to a new node pools in another zone even if we have configured it to remain in one zone by default.

Want to understand if we are getting Disaster Recovery in current setup or not.

Comment: If your node pool is only assigned to 1 zone, then if that zone goes down then you're SOL.  If your node pool has multiple zones, then instances should spin up on the "still available" zone.

Comment: Do you have any tolerations on your workloads ?

Comment: Thanks @Matthew , This confuses me. So if this is the case how is regional cluster helping us here. Does it means regional cluster doesn't remain regional if we provision it in Standard form where nodes are assigned to single zone? What's difference between this setup and zonal cluster then?

Comment: @boredabdel We have tolerations like for lower environments we are scheduling pods on cost optimized worker pool and for prod ones we are scheduling it on application pools.

Comment: A regional cluster ensures that the control plane is replicated across zones within a region, so if a given zone goes down you can still control your cluster.  However, the individual nodes running your workloads need to be configured to be spread amongst zones.